# Some repos not working-- some are. Packages cannot be found

Tags: 22.04

Repos are present in `/etc/apt/source.list.d`.

Well-known, well-supported repos (specifically, `docker` and `unityhub`) are added per documentation and show up in `sudo apt update`, but any packages I attempt to install cannot be located.

I have been able to navigate to the URL in `docker.list` and manually download and install packages, which isn't ideal. That file:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   jammy stable
```

`unityhub.list` is added [per the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/hub/manual/InstallHub.html#install-hub-linux), but packages cannot be located and I cannot navigate directly to the URL. That file:

```
deb https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable main
```

I run `sudo apt install unity-hub` and see:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package unity-hub
```

I tried re-installing another package from my repos, thinking maybe something about how these in `source.list.d` are added to the list is broken. I was able to re-install from the `protonvpn` repo just fine. (Note, if it's relevant: I am not running a VPN as I work through this.)

I tried researching this but have come up empty. Anyone have an idea of what I can try?

EDIT:
Here are the contents of my `sources.list` file. There was more in here-- a lot of commented lines-- but I regenerated the file while trying to troubleshoot the issue:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
```

Comment: Many questions on this site ask about protonvpn breaking networking.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, thank you for the information. I am not currently running Proton VPN. I just used that as an arbitrary example of a repo that worked historically and continues to work. Are you saying that adding that repo may have broken access to other repos?

Comment: I've just read a lot of questions here where people remove protonvpn and then networking is broken on their system.

Comment: Try running `apt-cache policy unity-hub`.

Comment: @Liso, I get `N: Unable to locate package unity-hub`.

Comment: Post the contents of your sources list.

Comment: @David contents added in edit

Comment: You will probably want to include jammy-updates and jammy-security in your sources or you will never get any updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the last two repositories I downloaded not working was a coincidence, not a pattern. I reinstalled Ubuntu and the Unity repo still didn't work right.

I ended up installing Unity Hub manually by following these instructions: https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/GettingStartedInstallingHub.html